# Using jQuery validate rule twice for a field

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate an input field that holds a user's date of birth, and I need to do **two checks** - *1.* Make sure the user is 18 years old and *2.* Make sure his/her age isn't over 100.

My custom validate method -

```
$.validator.addMethod(
       "datediff",
       function(value, element, diff_years) {
          var curr_date = new Date().getFullYear();
          var element_date = Date.parse($(element).val()).getFullYear();
          return element_date >= curr_date - diff_years;
       }
);
```

And here's how I add the rule.

```
var validator = $('form').validate({
     rules: {
        'dob': {datediff: 18}
     },
     messages: {
         dob: {datediff: 'You have to be 18 or more!'}
     }
});
```

How do I reuse the `datediff` rule twice, so that I can do both the checks? I tried just appending another `datediff` rule, but that didn't work.

**Edit:** I also need to show 2 distinct messages - for example - 1. *"You have to be 18 or more"* for the first condition, and *"You cannot be more than 100"* for the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need two unique messages, then you'll need two unique rules/methods.  You can put your common code into a single function and call it from within the custom method.

Something like this...

```
function datediff(value, diff_years) {
    var curr_date = new Date().getFullYear();
    var element_date = Date.parse(value.getFullYear();
    return element_date >= curr_date - diff_years;
}

$.validator.addMethod( "over18", function(value, element) {
    // your custom function below
    // var result = datediff(value, 18);
    // return true if age is greater than 18
    // return false and error message will display
}, "You must be over 18");

$.validator.addMethod( "under100", function(value, element) {
    // your custom function below
    // var result = datediff(value, 100);
    // return true if age is less than 100
    // return false and error message will display
}, "You must be under 100");

$('form').validate({
     rules: {
         dob: {
             over18: true,
             under100: true
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: Well, this comes closest to my intent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle 2 different messages, then probably you can use `max` and `min`

> [**max**](http://jqueryvalidation.org/max-method#value): Makes the element require a given maximum.
>   [**min**](http://jqueryvalidation.org/min-method#value): Makes the element require a given minimum.

**Rules:**

```
    rules: {
        dob: {
            min: 18,
            max: 100,
            required: true
        }
    }
```

**Messages displayed:**

```
    messages: {
        dob: {
            required: "Please enter the age",
            min: "Enter the age above 18",
            max: "Age should be below 100"
        }
    }
```

Check out in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/23/)

Comment: How do I use the `min` and `max` variables in my custom `datediff` method?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Range rule:

```
rules: {
field: {
  required: true,
    range: [18, 100]
  }
}
```

Source: http://jqueryvalidation.org/range-method

Comment: Ah this looks interesting. Would I be able to show different `messages` for both margins?

Comment: I don't think that would be possible as you can only set one message per validation. I will try and think of a solution with two messages